# How to git patch on last x commits on specific subdirectory

Tags: git

I have previously performed a `git filter-branch` on a repo so as to migrate a subset of the codebase, retaining it's history, to another repository.

`repo-old/x/y/z --> repo-new/z`

I now want to go back and patch apply recent commits from the old repo to the new one.

I know how to find the commits on the old repo that are relevant to the subdirectory z:

`git log --name-status -<number> x/y/z`

But how do I create an (ideally single) patch file from the old repo with only those commits from specific subdirectory z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to make patch out of last N commits in `repo1` limited to changes in dir `x/y/z` and apply it to `repo2`, which (I assume) consists of subtree `z` splitted from `repo1`.

In `repo1`:

```
$ git diff HEAD~N z/y/z > ~/example.patch
```

In `repo2`:

```
$ patch -p3 < ~/example.patch
```

Note -p3 parameter passed to `patch` here - it means "remove first three elements of paths affected by patch". You want 'z/y' removed, patch has 'a/z/y' (as is normal for patches), that's why you need to pass `-p3`.